# HTML email, table rowspan wrong in Safari

Tags: safari, html-table, html-email

Im trying to create a email template, with tables. The td elements in Safari has an incorrect height when I give an rowspan.

[image: Table that goes wrong]
I gave the TD's a red border and the div inside an green border. As you see the TD's height is too big

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/J1Yph9

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper"
        style="width: 100%; height: 100%; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: Arial,&amp; quot; Helvetica Neue&amp;quot; , Helvetica ,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; text-align: left; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
        <table
            style="padding: 0px; border: medium none; border-collapse: separate; background-color: rgb(232, 232, 232); height: 510px; width: 610px; margin: 0px auto; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: Arial,&amp; quot; Helvetica Neue&amp;quot; , Helvetica ,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; text-align: left;"
            bgcolor="rgb(232, 232, 232)" border="0" cellpadding="0"
            cellspacing="10" width="610px">
            <tbody>
                <tr
                    style="height: 40px; max-height: 40px; vertical-align: top; overflow: hidden; border: medium none;"
                    valign="top">
                    <td
                        style="vertical-align: top; overflow: hidden; border: medium none; background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0); height: 90px; max-height: 90px; width: 290px; max-width: 290px;"
                        rowspan="2" colspan="2" height="90px" bgcolor="rgb(255, 0, 0)"
                        valign="top" width="290px"><div
                            class=" item"
                            style="padding: 0px; overflow: hidden; background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0); color: rgb(51, 51, 51); margin: 0px; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 290px; height: 90px; position: initial;">
                            <div class="drop-block-content "
                                style="box-sizing: border-box; background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">
                                <div class="textContent ng-binding "
                                    style="box-sizing: border-box; padding: 18px; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: Arial,&amp; quot; Helvetica Neue&amp;quot; , Helvetica ,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; text-align: left;">
                                    <p>widget1</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div></td>
                    <td
                        style="vertical-align: top; overflow: hidden; border: medium none; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); height: 140px; max-height: 140px; width: 140px; max-width: 140px;"
                        rowspan="3" colspan="1" height="140px"
                        bgcolor="rgb(255, 255, 255)" valign="top" width="140px"><div
                            class=" item"
                            style="padding: 0px; overflow: hidden; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(51, 51, 51); margin: 0px; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 140px; height: 140px; position: initial;">
                            <div class="drop-block-content "
                                style="box-sizing: border-box;">
                                <div class="textContent ng-binding "
                                    style="box-sizing: border-box; padding: 18px; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: Arial,&amp; quot; Helvetica Neue&amp;quot; , Helvetica ,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; text-align: left;">
                                    <p>widget2</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div></td>
                    <td
                        style="vertical-align: top; overflow: hidden; border: medium none; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); height: 240px; max-height: 240px; width: 140px; max-width: 140px;"
                        rowspan="5" colspan="1" height="240px"
                        bgcolor="rgb(255, 255, 255)" valign="top" width="140px"><div
                            class=" item"
                            style="padding: 0px; overflow: hidden; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(51, 51, 51); margin: 0px; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 140px; height: 240px; position: initial;">
                            <div class="drop-block-content "
                                style="box-sizing: border-box;">
                                <div class="textContent ng-binding "
                                    style="box-sizing: border-box; padding: 18px; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: Arial,&amp; quot; Helvetica Neue&amp;quot; , Helvetica ,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; text-align: left;">
                                    <p>widget3</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr
                    style="height: 40px; max-height: 40px; vertical-align: top; overflow: hidden; border: medium none;"
                    valign="top"></tr>
                <tr
                    style="height: 40px; max-height: 40px; vertical-align: top; overflow: hidden; border: medium none;"
                    valign="top">
                    <td
                        style="vertical-align: top; overflow: hidden; border: medium none; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); height: 90px; max-height: 90px; width: 290px; max-width: 290px;"
                        rowspan="2" colspan="2" height="90px" bgcolor="rgb(255, 255, 255)"
                        valign="top" width="290px"><div
                            class=" item"
                            style="padding: 0px; overflow: hidden; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(51, 51, 51); margin: 0px; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 290px; height: 90px; position: initial;">
                            <div class="drop-block-content "
                                style=" box-sizing: border-box;">
                                <div class="textContent ng-binding "
                                    style="box-sizing: border-box; padding: 18px; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: Arial,&amp; quot; Helvetica Neue&amp;quot; , Helvetica ,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; text-align: left;">
                                    <p>widget4</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr
                    style="height: 40px; max-height: 40px; vertical-align: top; overflow: hidden; border: medium none;"
                    valign="top">
                    <td
                        style="vertical-align: top; overflow: hidden; border: medium none; background-color: rgb(0, 76, 255); height: 190px; max-height: 190px; width: 140px; max-width: 140px;"
                        rowspan="4" colspan="1" height="190px" bgcolor="rgb(0, 76, 255)"
                        valign="top" width="140px"><div
                            class=" item"
                            style="padding: 0px; overflow: hidden; background-color: rgb(0, 76, 255); color: rgb(51, 51, 51); margin: 0px; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 140px; height: 190px; position: initial;">
                            <div class="drop-block-content "
                                style=" box-sizing: border-box; background-color: rgb(0, 76, 255);">
                                <div class="textContent ng-binding "
                                    style="box-sizing: border-box; padding: 18px; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: Arial,&amp; quot; Helvetica Neue&amp;quot; , Helvetica ,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; text-align: left;">
                                    <p>widget5</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr
                    style="height: 40px; max-height: 40px; vertical-align: top; overflow: hidden; border: medium none;"
                    valign="top">
                    <td
                        style="vertical-align: top; overflow: hidden; border: medium none; background-color: rgb(0, 255, 178); height: 290px; max-height: 290px; width: 140px; max-width: 140px;"
                        rowspan="6" colspan="1" height="290px" bgcolor="rgb(0, 255, 178)"
                        valign="top" width="140px"><div
                            class=" item"
                            style="padding: 0px; overflow: hidden; background-color: rgb(0, 255, 178); color: rgb(51, 51, 51); margin: 0px; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 140px; height: 290px; position: initial;">
                            <div class="drop-block-content "
                                style=" box-sizing: border-box; background-color: rgb(0, 255, 178);">
                                <div class="textContent ng-binding "
                                    style="box-sizing: border-box; padding: 18px; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: Arial,&amp; quot; Helvetica Neue&amp;quot; , Helvetica ,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; text-align: left;">
                                    <p>widget6</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div></td>
                    <td
                        style="vertical-align: top; overflow: hidden; border: medium none; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); height: 140px; max-height: 140px; width: 140px; max-width: 140px;"
                        rowspan="3" colspan="1" height="140px"
                        bgcolor="rgb(255, 255, 255)" valign="top" width="140px"><div
                            class=" item"
                            style="padding: 0px; overflow: hidden; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(51, 51, 51); margin: 0px; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 140px; height: 140px; position: initial;">
                            <div class="drop-block-content "
                                style=" box-sizing: border-box;">
                                <div class="textContent ng-binding "
                                    style="box-sizing: border-box; padding: 18px; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: Arial,&amp; quot; Helvetica Neue&amp;quot; , Helvetica ,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; text-align: left;">
                                    <p>widget7</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr
                    style="height: 40px; max-height: 40px; vertical-align: top; overflow: hidden; border: medium none;"
                    valign="top">
                    <td
                        style="vertical-align: top; overflow: hidden; border: medium none; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); height: 240px; max-height: 240px; width: 140px; max-width: 140px;"
                        rowspan="5" colspan="1" height="240px"
                        bgcolor="rgb(255, 255, 255)" valign="top" width="140px"><div
                            class=" item"
                            style="padding: 0px; overflow: hidden; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(51, 51, 51); margin: 0px; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 140px; height: 240px; position: initial;">
                            <div class="drop-block-content "
                                style=" box-sizing: border-box;">
                                <div class="textContent ng-binding "
                                    style="box-sizing: border-box; padding: 18px; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: Arial,&amp; quot; Helvetica Neue&amp;quot; , Helvetica ,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; text-align: left;">
                                    <p>widget8</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr
                    style="height: 40px; max-height: 40px; vertical-align: top; overflow: hidden; border: medium none;"
                    valign="top"></tr>
                <tr
                    style="height: 40px; max-height: 40px; vertical-align: top; overflow: hidden; border: medium none;"
                    valign="top">
                    <td
                        style="vertical-align: top; overflow: hidden; border: medium none; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); height: 140px; max-height: 140px; width: 290px; max-width: 290px;"
                        rowspan="3" colspan="2" height="140px"
                        bgcolor="rgb(255, 255, 255)" valign="top" width="290px"><div
                            class=" item"
                            style="padding: 0px; overflow: hidden; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(51, 51, 51); margin: 0px; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 290px; height: 140px; position: initial;">
                            <div class="drop-block-content "
                                style=" box-sizing: border-box;">
                                <div class="textContent ng-binding "
                                    style="box-sizing: border-box; padding: 18px; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: Arial,&amp; quot; Helvetica Neue&amp;quot; , Helvetica ,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; text-align: left;">
                                    <p>widget9</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr
                    style="height: 40px; max-height: 40px; vertical-align: top; overflow: hidden; border: medium none;"
                    valign="top"></tr>
                <tr
                    style="height: 40px; max-height: 40px; vertical-align: top; overflow: hidden; border: medium none;"
                    valign="top"></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I know before creating this table what the height of each TD must be. (Calculation of the amount rows + cellspacing). It goes prefectly in each browser expect for (Safari and thus the email client of an iPad).

Answer (score 0):

This will not work in the majority of email clients. A lot of your css and your html is web based which will not be recognized or processed. There is also a lot of extra stylings that are not necessary and the structure it is built in is prone to potential issues.

I would definitely:

1. Declare an XHTML doctype
2. use tables for all structure and layout
3. use html attributes instead of CSS wherever possible
4. div styles are inconsistent across clients, so usually better to style a parent table or td tag
5. rowspan and colspan tend to be inconsistent, it is better to use nested tables or a similar method instead.

Go here to see what css is applicable to what email client: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/.

I would also go here for general tips in building HTML emails: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/build-an-html-email-template-from-scratch--webdesign-12770

Using browser rendering is a very poor substitute for live email testing as the browsers usually have a different preprocessor than the email clients.  Your best bet is to use a service like Email on Acid or Litmus to test your emails on most of the major email clients.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I added an XHTML docType to my email. 
I tried to create this structure with a nested Table but I was unable.

I 'fixed' my problem the easy way out, I made this structure into DIV's with position absolute and Im showing the DIV's when you view the email on a iPad/iPhone. In other email clients I'm showing the table html. I know its an cheap fix but It was it was only way to get it to work on an iPhone/iPad.